# How can I wrap Native Sol in JS?

Tags: spl-token, web3.js

I am trying to wrap SOL in a typescript application. I am looking at the example found at https://spl.solana.com/token#example-wrapping-sol-in-a-token.

I am running into issues importing createSyncNativeInstruction from @solana/spl-token. I don't see such a function defined in @solana/spl-token v0.2.0. I'm assuming it was removed and the docs were not updated. What is the most up to date and recommended way to wrap sol with JS on the latest spl-token implementation?

Comment: Function can be found here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/instructions/syncNative.ts#L28

Answer (score 2):

#### How to manage wrapped SOL

Wrapped SOL just like any other token mint. The difference is using syncNative and creating token accounts specifically on the `NATIVE_MINT` address.

**Create Token Account**

Like Create Token Account but replace mint with `NATIVE_MINT`

```
import { NATIVE_MINT } from "@solana/spl-token";
```

**Add Balance**

There are two ways to add balance for Wrapped SOL

**1. By SOL Transfer**

```
let tx = new Transaction().add(
  // trasnfer SOL
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: alice.publicKey,
    toPubkey: ata,
    lamports: amount,
  }),
  // sync wrapped SOL balance
  createSyncNativeInstruction(ata)
);
```

**2. By Token Transfer**

```
let tx = new Transaction().add(
  // create token account
  SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: alice.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: auxAccount.publicKey,
    space: ACCOUNT_SIZE,
    lamports:
      (await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptAccount(connection)) + amount, // rent + amount
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  }),
  // init token account
  createInitializeAccountInstruction(
    auxAccount.publicKey,
    NATIVE_MINT,
    alice.publicKey
  ),
  // transfer WSOL
  createTransferInstruction(auxAccount.publicKey, ata, alice.publicKey, amount),
  // close aux account
  createCloseAccountInstruction(
    auxAccount.publicKey,
    alice.publicKey,
    alice.publicKey
  )
);
```

---

[source](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-manage-wrapped-sol)

Comment: Could you extract the relevant code from the cookbook. In the case of cookbook links changing or other factors, your answer will still be useful